# Why does GCC generate different opcodes for multiplication based on a value of the constant?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction

I was playing around with GCC disassembler on [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) and I noticed that GCC starting version 4.6 compiles multiplication differently. I have the following two functions:

```
unsigned m126(unsigned i)
{
    return i * 126;
}

unsigned m131(unsigned i)
{
    return i * 131;
}
```

`m126` compiles into:

```
mov eax, edi
mov edx, 126
imul eax, edx
ret
```

And `m131` compiles into:

```
imul eax, edi, 131
ret
```

Why is the difference? GCC 4.5 generates the same opcode in both cases.

[A link to the actual example on GCC Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22:3,%22filterAsm%22:%7B%22labels%22:true,%22directives%22:true,%22commentOnly%22:true,%22intel%22:true,%22colouriseAsm%22:true%7D,%22compilers%22:%5B%7B%22source%22:%22unsigned%20m126%28unsigned%20i%29%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20i%20*%20126;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnunsigned%20m131%28unsigned%20i%29%5Cn%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20i%20*%20131;%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22,%22compiler%22:%22/usr/bin/g++-4.7%22,%22options%22:%22-O2%20-march=native%22%7D%5D%7D).

Comment: Because it generates different code if the number is above a signed byte's max value.

Comment: @Doorknob: That's an interesting hypothesis, why would it need to do this?

Comment: @Doorknob: True, I didn't notice that. I was looking only at crossing the 8-bit boundary. Is it more efficient or compact this way?

Comment: It's certainly not more compact (I've checked the machine code). I don't see why it would be more efficient either.

Comment: is mov edx,126 not using just "one byte for the constant"? - in which case it's possibly a byte shorter than the 32-bit constant for imul eax,edi,126

Comment: `gcc` 4.7.2 (-O3) uses the same instruction sequence for both functions: `imull   $126, 4(%esp), %eax` and `imull   $131, 4(%esp), %eax`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found this in `gcc/config/i386/i386.md` (see the comment on the top):

```
;; imul $8/16bit_imm, regmem, reg is vector decoded.
;; Convert it into imul reg, reg
;; It would be better to force assembler to encode instruction using long
;; immediate, but there is apparently no way to do so.
(define_peephole2
  [(parallel [(set (match_operand:SWI248 0 "register_operand")
           (mult:SWI248
            (match_operand:SWI248 1 "nonimmediate_operand")
            (match_operand:SWI248 2 "const_int_operand")))
          (clobber (reg:CC FLAGS_REG))])
   (match_scratch:SWI248 3 "r")]
  "TARGET_SLOW_IMUL_IMM8 && optimize_insn_for_speed_p ()
   && satisfies_constraint_K (operands[2])"
  [(set (match_dup 3) (match_dup 2))
   (parallel [(set (match_dup 0) (mult:SWI248 (match_dup 0) (match_dup 3)))
          (clobber (reg:CC FLAGS_REG))])]
{
  if (!rtx_equal_p (operands[0], operands[1]))
    emit_move_insn (operands[0], operands[1]);
})
```

Seems like it has something to do with instruction decoding (sorry I'm not an expert)

Comment: It seems like this is something related. But I don't really understand how this code explains the difference.

Comment: After studying it for some time it starts to make sense. Seems when `TARGET_SLOW_IMUL_IMM8` is defined and `satisfies_constraint_K` is true (which is defined in `constrains.md` and mean that the constant is in `[-128, 127]` range) it replaces the 3 operand `imul` with the 3 instruction combo. It looks like `imul` with `imm8` could be slow on some CPUs.

Comment: In `i386.c` there's a bit of code that says: `/* X86_TUNE_SLOW_IMUL_IMM8: Imul of 8-bit constant is vector path on AMD machines. */ m_CORE2I7 | m_K8 | m_AMDFAM10 | m_BDVER | m_BTVER | m_GENERIC64`. It kinda makes sense now. Thanks.